Update One Collection on MongoDB from Python
I'm trying to update one collection on mongoDB adding to set if the key not exist or creating the set.
That's my code and database schema:
result = collection.update_one(
            {"date": meal.date, "diets": {"$elemMatch": {meal.dietName: {"$exists": True}}}},
            {"$push": {f"diets.$[diet].meal": meal_dict[meal.dietName]["meal"]}},
            array_filters=[{"diet": meal.dietName}]
        )
        print(result.matched_count)
        print(result.modified_count)

        if result.matched_count == 0:
            result = collection.update_one({"date": meal.date}, {"$addToSet": {"diets": meal_dict}}, upsert=True)

matched_count = 1 but modified_count = 0.
How can I fix it?

What do the documets look like?
